# Where does a given inertial frame of reference end?

Tags: spacetime, reference-frames, inertial-frames

I am told that the reason the galaxy does not spin around me (relative to me) at a trillion times the speed of light when I do a pirouette is the inertial frame of reference to which I am confined along with the rest of humanity.

My question is: where does this frame of reference end?

To the best of my limited understanding, gravity doesn't just stop at some point. Anything that has mass has gravity; gravitational waves (or whatever) extend from the mass spherically. They weaken as they get further away from the source, they get pushed around by other, more powerful, gravity waves, they become progressively weaker as the distance increases, but do they ever vanish completely, i.e. get reduced to absolute zero? Or do they become weaker and weaker forever, without zeroing out? And if so, where does a frame of reference end?

Comment: What do you mean, "the inertial frame to which you are confined"? Standing on earth and taking your position as the origin and e.g. your height and viewing direction as axes *is not an inertial frame* (the Coriolis force occurs in it, for one). Frames are not "boxes" you're "confined" to , they are *coordinate systems*. Coordinate systems don't have any extent, they neither "start" nor "end". I don't understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: A coordinate frame is not a physical thing. It's only a mathematical tool. It's quite possible (and simpler in many ways, since it renders the principle of general covariance a fairly trivial statement) to do relativity entirely without coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Classical physics states that an inertial reference frame is a co-ordinate system based around a point with its own time. That is that anything that occurs around the origin of that system is all relative to it's own time.

If like to look at a pirouette this way, you can say that all the gravity from all the mass in the universe is fact effecting you through Newton's laws of motion and his inverse square law of gravitation.

$$ F = \frac{GM_{1}M_{2}}{r^{2}} $$

Such that for when distance r tends to infinity, the force experienced is negligible.

However, when you really start to look into celestial mechanics, you see that vector resolution through systems of spheres is not linear, i.e systems can be someone enclosed due to dominant forces.
But then we also noticed that there were certain points in orbits that has no net force, called Lagrange points.
These points are a result of a confluence of forces that cause asymptotic freedom which ended classical mechanics in Lissajous figures.

Because the speed of light is a limit is 300000000 meters per second and that no object that exceed this limit, the notion of an absolute reference frame had to be abandoned (Michelson-Morley experiment revealed no absolute medium). Thus the inverse square law was no longer an accurate theory.

Einstein then went on to look at other geometries that fit a more elegant principle of relativism, chiefly through the equivalence principle, and theorized general relativity.
If you look at your pirouette through general relativity, you can instead look at yourself inside your own light cone; a reference frame of an event governed by the speed of light and it's imposed geometry, going along your own world-line that is determined by other events in the local group.

Comment: Could you be more illustrative about the last sentence?